# php function inside of jquery mobile creates "error loading page" in server?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have created a function inside of my jquery mobile code. its working fine locally. But in the server where I have hosted its not working properly. 
please help 
Here is a sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Site title</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/scbd.ico">   
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>


    </head> 


    <body> 
        <div data-role="page" class="type-index">

            <div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
                    <h1 id="jqm-logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></h1>
                    <a href="index.php" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>


            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div id="header_rightpart">
                <a name="header"><h2>sfdshsjdhfjdsh</h2></a>                
                </div>
            <?php 
                          here I have written the function
                            ?>
```

But there is nothing wrong with the function its working fine in the local machine. But cant understand why it is not working in the server. I am getting error "error loading page". Is it just because of using multipel php tag?? I mean I have used `<?php ?>` twice in the page. Please help me to find out the solution

Comment: multiple `<?php ?>` tags is not the problem definitely. Are you using different version of PHP in the localhost and server?

Comment: Unfortunately, without knowing more about your server, this could be a multitude of things. can we get more server info? What PHP is it runing, what did you use locally, are all files in place? Where you using apache and something diff on the server? What is the folder structure? Are you sure you included all the proper files? have you run the page on your server without the php in it to see if this is a PHP issue. Sadly, "Error Loading Page" can have a lot of different meanings depending on a dozen or more things.

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: hi, thanks everyone for your reply . But actually I am not sure whats the version of php in the server. If the version creates this problem then I have to change it. @Omar I get this error when I click on a link to go to this page.

Comment: @MISJHA my local machine has PHP Version 5.4.7 and in server it is PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: @Hriju: Are you using any of the following in your code: namespaces, closures, iterators? If so, you're getting a 500 due to those not being available in PHP 5.2.

Comment: `error loading page` it means, the page couldnt be located. check your links and pages structure on your server.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld you are right.

Comment: @Omar there is nothing wrong with link. It was problem with a php variable. Which I have mentioned below. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution. I declared a variable  like `$names=[];` it did not work on my server. That was reason behind the error. I think this was because of php version. Sever php version was 5.2.17 and my local is 5.4.7 so it worked fine on local machine. But something was wrong with server php version.

```
function f_do ($rootname)
 {
$query = "SELECT course_name FROM onlinecourses WHERE root_name = '$rootname'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

//$names=[]; this caused error
//$row=[]; this caused error
if($num > 0)
{

    while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $names[] = $row['course_name'];
    }


}
return $names; 
}
```

commented part shows the variable.